# DMG4800 MOSFET running hot (while Si4804 runs cool)

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor

I'm working on a BLDC control system for a micromotor, and have been using the [Vishay Si4804 MOSFETs](https://www.vishay.com/docs/72061/si4804bd.pdf) in output stage.

Due to availability issues, I ordered [Diodes Inc DMG4800LSD-13](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31858.pdf) for a second board, since they were a bit cheaper, and the specifications match up well.

The problem: 4804 runs cool to touch, regardless of current draw. The 4800 runs WAY hotter, and one even blew during testing. Any idea what could be going on?

I'm running at a PWM frequency of 40kHz. The current draw during normal operation is only ~200mA.[image: outoput stage]
[image: A4964 drive circuit]

EDIT:
The driver for this output stage is the Allegro A4964. I'm currently using a dead time of 1us.

Experimenting with gate resistor value, I can get the 4800 MOSFET to function without heating. Probably the slow turn-on and turn-off, and perhaps the small overlap, caused the heating.

Gate drive waveforms with 100 ohm gate resistor:
[image: 100 ohm gate resistor]

Gate drive waveforms with 33 ohm gate resistor:
[image: 33 ohm gate resistor]

**Update:**

I have switched to the 6016LSD MOSFETs and removed the GS resistors. They draw less current than the 4804's. These are the gate drive waveforms measured individually, since my cheapo scope doesn't to differential measurements. Both measured from Source to Gate.
[image: 6016 low/high gate voltages]

Here I can start seeing quite some ringing on the high side gate. Does this warrant a higher value gate resistor again?

Comment: Given the information here ... no datasheets, no idea of gate drive waveforms or amplitudes or how the high side bootstrap is implemented ... or whether the high side, low side or both have problems, ... I'd say you have a bit of work to do.

Comment: A schematic of the driving circuit would be helpful.

Comment: Added info about the driver circuit - which is an A4964 chip from Allegro.

Comment: I notice that the Diodes Inc part datasheet does *not* have a safe operating area graph; without that, all bets are off. I won't use a FET that does not have the SOA graph in a power switching application. https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31858.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both transistors are rated up to Vds=30V, you have 36V as supply. You would need at least 50V or even 75V rated devices.

Then, 100 ohm gate resistor is a way too high value if you want to switch at 40kHz, do calculate rising and falling switch time and you will see that your circuit doesn't even turn completely on, so you have lot of switching loses.

The resistor connected between gate and source, tells me that you don't have a gate driver IC, but rather some discrete components to drive the MOSFETs, which is undocumented in your question, which also could be a source of problems.

Comment: Indeed the transistors are rated to 30V only. I've been using a lower voltage power supply, but will switch to another transistor to handle the full 36V:
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMTH6016LSD.pdf

I also experimented with the gate resistor value - at 100ohm, considering ~800pF capacitance in the MOSFET, I get a cutoff at 2MHz. With a scope I can see that this might indeed be a bit too low. A value around 33ohm seems to work better - reducing the ringing enough, while not slowing down the gate charge to get overlap.

Comment: Remove also the gate to source transistors 27k, as they are not needed. The driver has it's own internal resistors. Reduce the PWM frequency, don't think you have any benefits running on 40kHz. Whatch out for Qg charge on MOSFETS. Use transistors with lowest Qq VS. Rdson. Perhaps some OptiMOS would perform better.

Comment: The reason I added the GS resistors was that they were present on the reference design from Allegro 
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mikrocontroller.net%2Fattachment%2F368732%2FA4964JPDemoR0.pdf

Comment: @ncore That's strange. Do you have any document accompanying the schematics? There is very little known on  the A4964. The datasheet says that you don't even need gate resistors and that it has its own pull down resistors, so in case off power outage the MOSFETS gates are pulled down.

Comment: Indeed there is not much documentation about this chip, except the datasheet itself. This reference design, along with the serial tool, I found in this forum thread https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/453872

I'll check how it performs without the GS resistors. Thanks a lot for your helpful comments!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a clue in the 100R gate drive waveform.

Turning on, Vgs rises to a plateau (at Vth) then rises only a little further once past the plateau. You can see this at 33R too, but not as clearly. The following is partially speculation because we still don't know the driver supply voltage.

That Vgs plateau suggests, the full gate drive is only slightly higher than Vth. This isn't enough to turn a MOSFET fully on - you want to aim for about 2* Vth. (You will notice that Ron decreases between Vgs=4.5 and 10V - if your Vgs < 4.5V as the plateau suggests, increasing drive voltage to nearer 10V (or choosing lower Vgs FETs) may help.

The ON resistance will then exceed its datasheet value, and be very dependent on conditions like temperature AND vary significantly between batches of transistors.
However, the 4804 (which works) is the device with a higher spread of Vth values and a higher maximum Vth, so this is not by itself conclusive.

Comment: I think the reason for the plateau is that I could only use a common ground for measurement - when measuring G-S individually on the phases, waveform looks as expected (see my latest update to original question). The gate drive voltage is 11V.

Comment: 11V is certainly adequate.